# why is shade flat imporant?

Tags: vertices, shaders

i'd like to know why low poly is important because i find subdivision surface much better to work with , without the shade flat and shade smooth! i realised that when someone is creating a character , they start with the shade flat, i did the same but at some point i knew i could activate subdivision surface and keep going from there and i got a great result! when i changed back to shade flat to see how it was, it was a mess, i started organizing the polygons in shade flat as i saw in blenderella cvideo course, but when i did it my subdivided mesh changed drastically and looked very ugly without the details i wanted. So, if i model a character, do i really have to put my shade flat mesh in order? because i am very happy with i have so far! pls check the comparisson , do i really have to care to the low poly version? because i think the results i got so far with the subd surface are better

[image]

[image: i tweaked the vertices w/ subd surface on , but my shade flat version looks horrible]

Comment: I'm not quite sure why would you need to set shading to flat?
From what I see you have the low poly version, did you sculpted first or modeled it this way?

Comment: For a rendered animation, you would be correct to apply smooth shading along with a subdivision modifier. This all changes when you're trying to use models in other applications such as a game engine or in simulations where the amount of triangles you have is an extremely important factor. In game engines, you're trying to pack as much detail in a model while using the least amount of geometry you can. Smooth shading in conjunction with custom normals and normal maps is one of the most used paradigms. A game engine is going to take your unsubdivided model on the right much better than the left

Comment: As well the use of flat shading and keeping a low poly count may be used as an artistic choice. It really depends on your goals and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BlackCloud i first started with shade flat as a base , later i started tweaking only with subd version on, i am questioning this because if you check blenderella tutorial, she everytimechanges subd to flat, and i didnt understand that, i check the videos on youtub and everyone model flat first and ensure that the shade flat is in order , but i dont know why they would need to work with the shade flat as the subd is easier and looks better, i wanted to understand why

Comment: @aglet i am trying to make a character to import to unity, i was worried about my emsh because the shade flat of it is looking horrible and on tutorials, modellers  always make a good flat mesh to go later to subd , and i did the inverse , i tried to model in shade flat but it aalways looks weird as i am not good with geometry so i found better to work with subd , but why people always use shade flat? is it because of the UV mapping? if you check models for salle they are never in subd surface shade.